# MongoDB, MySQL or something third for my project?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, database

Ok guys.

I've begun developing a little sparetime project that might become big someday. Before I really get started, I want to be certain that I'm starting with the right setup. So I come to you.

I'm making a service, which will work mostly as a todolist/project planner.
In this system there will be an amount of users and an amount of tasks. Each task can be assigned to multiple users, and each user can have multiple tasks (many to many relation).

Until now I was planning to use MySQL, but a friend of mine, who is part of the project, sugested MongoDB instead. He tells me that it would increase performance and be more scaleable.
On the other hand I'm thinking that in order to either get all tasks assigned to a specific user, or all users assigned to a specifik task, one would need to use joins, which MongoDB doesnt have (or have in a cumbersome way as far as I have understood).

Now my question to you is "Which DB system would you suggest. MySQL or MongoDB or a third option? And why?"

Thank you for your time and your assistance.

Morten

Comment: Use what you know best but abstract the access to the data layer to some decent degree. If need be, you can always scale later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use MySQL at IGN to store person relationships (many-to-many like your use case), and have about 5M records in the relationship table. We have 4 MySQL servers in a cluster and the reads are distributed across 3 MySQL slaves. BTW you can always denormalize to optimize reads and penalizing writes among other things based on the read/write heavyness of your system.

We use the DAO pattern with Spring, so its fairly easy for us to swap DB providers through configuration (and by writing a Mongo/MySQL DAO Implementation as applicable). We have moved activities (like in Social Media) to Mongo almost a year ago but the person relationships are living happily in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

The comment to your post by Jonas says it all,

> If need be, you can always scale later.

This.

I am very much of the mindset that `If you don't have scaling problems, don't worry too much (if at all) about scaling problems.`  Why not use what is easiest, smartest and cleanest to ***deliver*** the features clients pay for (in my case at least!) This approach saves a lot of time and energy and is the proper one for 9 projects out of 10.

Learning a technology because it scales is great. Being tied to an unlearned technology and unknown technology because it scales in an upcoming project,  is not as great. There are many other factors than scalability, when using 3rd party stuff.

MySQL would seem to be a good choice MySQL being more mature and having loads of client libraries, ORM's and other timesaving technologies. MySQL can handle millions *(billions if you have the ram)* of rows.  I have yet to encounter a project it could not handle, and I have seen some pretty impressive datasets!

Of course, when you will need performance, sure maybe you will find yourself ripping out orm and sql generating code   to replace with your own hand tweaked queries,  but that day is way down the line and chances are, *that day will never even come*.

Mongodb,  although *it is real cool* I am sorry to say may well bring you issues having nothing to do with scaling.

My 2 cents, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

## MySQL

Either would likely work for your purposes, but your database seems relatively rigid in its structure, something which SQL deals well with. As such, I would recommend **MySQL**. A many-to-many relationship is relatively easy to implement and access, as well.

You may take a tiny bit of a performance hit, but in my experience, this is generally not extremely noticeable with smaller scale applications (i.e. databases with less than *millions* of entries). I do agree with @Jonas Elfström's comment, however: you should have an abstraction layer between your application and the database, so that should scaling become an issue, you can address it without too many problems.

Answer (score 0):

Stick with a relational database, it can handle many to many relationships and is fully featured for backup and recovery, high availability and importantly you will find that every developer you need is familiar with it. There are plenty of documented methods for scaling a relational database.

Pick an open source databases either MySQL or Postgres dependant upon which your team is most familiar with and how it integrates into the rest of your infrastructure stack.

Make sure you design your data model correctly most importantly the relationships between the entities.

Good luck!